# Using MigraDoc to generate PDF, the TM trademark symbol is not getting displayed in outline level text of PDF

Tags: pdf, migradoc

```
Paragraph paragraph1 = section.AddParagraph(string.Format("{0} {1}",  bulletNumber1, "6th Car CompanyName® ModelName™ xyz xyz"), "Heading1");
paragraph1.AddBookmark(string.Format("{0} {1}", bulletNumber1, "6th Car CompanyName® ModelName™ xyz xyz"));
```

In MigraDoc when I add Heading1 style an outline level is created in bookmarks. ® symbol for companyname is displayed properly but not TM symbol.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MigraDoc 1.50 where Unicode characters in bookmarks work. Available on NuGet, CodePlex, GitHub, SourceForge.

I presume you use MigraDoc 1.32 where Unicode in bookmarks did not work.